# Merging feature branches without branching all the way back from common ancestor?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Let's say I have a really straightforward branching situation like this, where there's a *dev* branch and a *production* branch, that at some point in the past have a common ancestor called *common*:

[image: graph1]

Now, it's time to make a new feature. We want the feature in *dev* today, and in *production* in a month. The simple thing to do would be to branch the feature off of *common*, and then merge it into *dev* and *production* when we want to:

[image: graph2]

But this time, I don't want to do this. I don't want to do this because *dev* and *production* have both changed so much since *common*, that it's going to really be a pain to develop this feature off of *common*.

What I'd really like to do, is develop it off of some later point in the tree, like this, just for my own happiness, so that all the new updates to *dev* can be present when I make the feature:

[image: graph3]

Now, of course this will work for merging the feature into *dev*, but when I merge this feature into *production*, it's going to bring in a whole bunch of stuff from *dev* that I really don't want.

One solution would be to merge *dev* and *production*.  But I really don't want to do this. I need stuff on *dev* that's not on *production*, possibly for a long time.

Granted, what I want will only even logically be possible as long as the feature does not mess with anything inside *dev* or *production* that would conflict.  But it really doesn't.  It's going' to be compatible with both, and the changes I made to *dev* since *common* are not even related to the feature. I just want them there when I'm making the feature. And I don't want to have to keep merging the feature into *dev* every single time I want to test anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's going' to be compatible with both, and the changes I made to `dev` since common are not even related to the `feature`

That means you can start on top of `dev`, then, when you want to merge `feature` in `prod`, you *rebase* `feature` on top of `prod`.

That way, you are bringing only feature commits on top of `prod`, which can the merge `feature` (fast-forward merge)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `feature` branch introduces 2 commits from some point in the `dev` branch:

```
                            F1---F2 [feature]
                           /
               D1---D2---D3---D4 [dev]
             /
...---COMMON
             \
               P1---P2---P3---P4 [production]
```

If your intent is to

1. Integrate the feature into the `dev` branch
2. Integrate the feature into the `production` branch
3. Merge the `dev` branch into the `production` branch

There is more than one way to get this done, depending on what you want the history to show. Assuming you want to minimize the number of non-fast-forward merges start with:

```
git rebase dev feature
git checkout dev
git merge feature
```

And you'll have

```
               D1---D2---D3---D4---F1'---F2' [feature, dev]
             /
...---COMMON
             \
               P1---P2---P3---P4 [production]
```

Then, if you want the feature in the `production` branch but you don't yet want to merge the `dev` branch, do:

```
git rebase --onto production <Commit ID of D4> feature
git checkout production
git merge feature
```

To get:

```
               D1---D2---D3---D4---F1'---F2' [dev]
             /
...---COMMON
             \
               P1---P2---P3---P4---F1''---F2'' [feature, production]
```

Finally you can integrate the `dev` branch with:

```
git rebase production dev
git checkout production
git merge dev
```

And you'll have:

```
...---COMMON---P1---P2---P3---P4---F1''---F2''---D1'---D2'---D3'---D4'
                                           |                        |
                                       [feature]            [production, dev]
```

Of couse, if you have conflicts you'll need to merge them accordingly.  See [The Perils of Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing) to avoid having two commits that have the same author, date, and message.